# MySQL - Searching From 3 tables with one query

Tags: mysql

I have 3 table

Table news:

```
id_post | news      | id_user
3       | IT news   | 1 
4       | game news | 2
```

Table user:

```
id_user | username
   1    | bocah
   2    | gundul
```

And Table vote

```
id_vote | id_post | id_user | LIKE
10      | 3       | 2       | 1
```

And this is my sql query:

```
SELECT post.*, username, like, SUM(vote.like) AS like FROM  post 
INNER JOIN user ON post.id_user=user.id_user 
INNER JOIN vote ON post.id_post=vote.id_post 
WHERE 
(`title` LIKE '%$word%' OR `username` LIKE '%$word%') AND post.id_user=user.id 
LIMIT 15
```

I just want to create search form from searching `post` or `user` based on keyword. Then display post, user's username which is also the author of post and total like in that news.

The problem is when keyword not match with any post or any user, my expectation, it should return an empty row. But it's not, it's return 1 row with NULL value.

Any answer to solve this?

Comment: LIKE is a reserved word in mysql. Therefore, this is *not* your query!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from getting one row when there is no match, you probably also get one row when there are multiple matches. I think this is because you have an aggregation (sum) without having a group by.

If I'm correct, adding a group by clause should solve the problem:

```
SELECT post.*, username, like, SUM(vote.like) AS like FROM  post 
INNER JOIN user ON post.id_user=user.id_user 
INNER JOIN vote ON post.id_post=vote.id_post 
WHERE 
(`title` LIKE '%$word%' OR `username` LIKE '%$word%') AND post.id_user=user.id 
GROUP BY post.id /* Or what's its name */
LIMIT 15
```

It will then, however, return results by post, so if you search for a user, you will still get all their posts (that is, the top 15), but my guess is that that's exactly what you want.